# Animation in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-animate

I have an animation that changes margin-left of an element that makes some element "appear" and others "disappear".  I had that code in JQuery, but I need to implement that in AngularJS 1.6.  I've made the margin-left change when needed, but I would like it to be animated like this:

```
("#container").animate({ marginLeft: nextMargin+'px' }, 1000);
```

I am trying something with ng-style, but can't get it to work:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-main-father" id="container" ng-style="customStyle ">
```

**Angular**

```
 var Container = angular.element(document.querySelector('#container'));
        var totalWidth = Container.prop('offsetWidth');        
        var oldMargin = Container.css('margin-left'); 
        $scope.customStyle = {
            'from { margin-left': oldMargin  + '; }',
            'to { margin-left': (-totalWidth / 3 * (index - 1)) + '}'
        };
```

Also, I'm doing this at runtime because the width changes and can't be done in css.

**UPDATE**

This is the actual working code:

```
var Container = angular.element(document.querySelector('#container'));
            var totalWidth = Container.prop('offsetWidth');        
            var oldMargin = Container.css('margin-left'); 
            $scope.customStyle = {
                'margin-left': (-totalWidth / 3 * (index - 1)) 
            };
```

Comment: Can you include the code where `$scope.customStyle` changes every time

Comment: @JohnVelasquez look at my update.

Comment: Try adding `$scope.apply()` below the `$scope.customStyle`